# Getting VBS-Script to change registry

Tags: vbscript, registry, skype, wsh

I have been trying a lot of different solutions to making a script that with 1 click can change some registry settins in *Skype*. I have attempted straight scripting even using delay and sending enter but nothing seems to work.

The closest I have gotten is the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Skype\Phone]
"ProxySetting"=-
"ProxyAddress"=-
"DisableUDP"=-
```

However this still results in a confirmation box from "*RegistryEditor*". I have tried getting the script to send enter and I have tried making a separate VBS script to run this file and sending enter twice to handle the confirmation box but with no "smooth" success.

What'd a proper solution be?

Comment: I found the solution to my own question.

You can run registry files silently like this:

    objShell.Run "regedit /s  \\path\registry.reg

or even like this:

    regedit.exe /s regfile.reg

Comment: Post the answer yourself so people can search and find the answer alongside the question.

Comment: I wish I could but I do not have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `regedit /s` is possible, but a little awkward, since you'd have to create a file with the settings and then import that file. And even if we ignored that, the solution still had the problem that `regedit` doesn't return a status code indicating whether the import was successful or not. The latter could be addressed by replacing `regedit.exe` with [`reg.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742021.aspx):

```
rc = objShell.Run("reg import \\host\share\registry.reg", 0, True)
```

However, it's unnecessary to import an external file. VBScript can directly create, manipulate and delete registry keys and values, either via a [`WshShell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sh.RegDelete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Skype\Phone\ProxySetting"
sh.RegDelete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Skype\Phone\ProxyAddress"
sh.RegDelete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Skype\Phone\DisableUDP"
```

or via [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Const HKLM = &h80000001
Const key  = "SOFTWARE\Policies\Skype\Phone"

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

rc1 = reg.DeleteValue(HKLM, key, "ProxySetting")
rc2 = reg.DeleteValue(HKLM, key, "ProxyAddress")
rc3 = reg.DeleteValue(HKLM, key, "DisableUDP")
```